# How do I make an if statement concerning a radiogroup with two radio buttons in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How do I make an if statement concerning a `TRadioGroup` with two radio buttons, so that it outputs text when checking a specific radio button in the `TRadioGroup`.

The `TradioGroup.Items` has those values:

- Male
- Female

So when the Male button is checked, it must output `'Mr'` and if the Female button is checked it must output `'Ms'` to a rich edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`ItemIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.ItemIndex)** property of the **[`TRadioGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup)** as

```
Case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
 0: //Add Mr to RichEdit;
 1: //Add Ms to RichEdit;
 //else if needed
end;
```

If you really need to use `if` then

```
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then
  //Add Mr to RichEdit
else
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 1 then
  //Add Ms to RichEdit;
//else if needed
```

You don't specify if you will **[`Clear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Clear)** the **[`TRichEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit)** component before adding the string, **[`Add`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Add)** or **[`Insert`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Insert)** the string to it, or even replace another one with it according to the `Index`, Thus I leave it up to you and just write comments.

Since you have two buttons (assuming `Mr` - `Ms` in that order), then the `ItemIdex` property of the `TRadioGroup` component will hold:

- `-1` if none of them has been selected.
- `0` means `'Mr'` selected.
- `1` means `'Ms'` selected.

Comment: He asked for an if statement.

Comment: I love your edits on the fly hahaha. Here, I'll delete the answer so you can get it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a if statement to determine what happens if a certain event happens .
In a radioGroup the index begins To count from 
0
1
2
3
etc.

````
    if TRadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then
    RedDisplay.Lines.add('Mr') //This displays Mr in the richedit
    else
    if TRadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 1 then
  RedDisplay.Lines.Add('Ms') ;  // this displays Ms in the richedit

    //You can add an extra else if ,if there is another button in the radioGroup.
```
````